# Unable to retrieve data as object

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller**

```
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("webuser");
        $data['extract'] = $this->webuser->myuser();
        $this->load->view("webview", $data);

        }
    }
    ?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
class Webuser extends CI_model {

    public function myuser (){
            $this->load->database();
            $q = $this->db->query("select * from user_accounts");
            return $q->result();
    }
}

?>
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head><title>web users</title></head>
<body>
<h1> Hello world </h1>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($extract as $data ): ?>
<tr>  
<td><?= $data->firstname;  ?></td> <td><?= $data->lastname; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
```

**Error**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$firstname
>
> Filename: views/webview.php
>
> Line Number: 8

**And**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$lastname
>
> Filename: views/webview.php
>
> Line Number: 8

Comment: what's your 'user_accounts' table structure ?

Comment: id int(3)  
First Name varchar(15)
last name varchar(15)

Comment: Your table fields are "First Name" and "Last Name" or "firstname" and "lastname" ? if its "First Name" and "Last Name" the try by changing to "firstname" and "lastname" .

Comment: @ranakrunal9 It worked... How foolish of me.. thank you soo much..

Answer (score 0):

Load database library

```
$this->load->library("database");
```

Before:

```
$this->load->database();
```